# Hide tr element from click within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a table structure (see snippet below) and my goal is to hide a `tr` element once I click on the `span` that reads `delete`. I need the specific `tr` where that `delete` is contained.

I already got a listener for the click event on the last span, the one that says "delete" working.

I've got several `tr` elements, is it possible to hide the `tr` where the span is contained (and therefore, all the contents)?

```js
    $(".delete_pm").click(function () {
        alert('hey');
        $(this).closest( "tr" ).hide(); // tried this from answers below but no luck, as you can see here
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="fjxtnw" checked />
            <strong>555555******4444</strong> (MasterCard)
            <label>(default)</label>
            <span id="fjxtnw" class="delete_pm"><label>delete</label></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Your snippet isn't working because your `<tr>` isn't inside a `<table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to search the parents. Provide it with `tr` as the selector, then simply hide it.

```js
$(".delete_pm").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="fjxtnw" checked />
      <strong>555555******4444</strong> (MasterCard)
      <label>(default)</label>
      <span id="fjxtnw" class="delete_pm"><label>delete</label></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your answer. I can't make it work though, can you insert a code snippet with that? I just tested on mine and nothing happens

Comment: Added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

have you try this,

```js
$(".delete_pm").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="credit-card" value="fjxtnw" checked />
      <strong>555555******4444</strong> (MasterCard)
      <label>(default)</label>
      <span id="fjxtnw" class="delete_pm"><label>delete</label></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Azzi, thanks for your answer. I can't make it work though, can you insert a code snippet with that? I just tested on mine and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

`closest` will give you the nearby parent with the matching selector.

`hide` will not remove the item from the DOM.If you want that also, you may chain the `remove` method call also.

```
$(".delete_pm").click(function () {

    var _this=$(this);
    _this.closest("tr").hide().remove();

});
```

[Here](http:////jsfiddle.net/sze98jpm/1/) is a working jsfiddle

Comment: Shyju, thanks for your answer. I can't make it work though, can you insert a code snippet with that? I just tested on mine and nothing happens